# ansible import_playbook with role tag

Tags: ansible, tags, roles

I have `setup.yml` with multiple roles:

setup.yml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: file-download, tags: files }
    - { role: setup-nginx, tags: nginx}
    - { role: restart-vm, tags: restartvm }
    - { role: file-upload, tags: upload}
    - { role: intall-vm, tags: installvm}
    - { role: create-backup, tags: backup}
```

From command line I can run:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory setup.yml --tags=nginx 
ansible-playbook -i inventory setup.yml --tags=restartvm
```

How can I import_playbooks to `new.yml` playbook and run only roles which have tag `nginx` and `restartvm`?

new.yml:

```
- import_playbook: setup.yml --tags=nginx
- import_playbook:setup.yml --tags=restartvm
```

I get following error:

```
ERROR! Invalid variable name in vars specified for PlaybookInclude: '--tags' is not a valid variable name
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

This will not work. You can feed `import_playbook` only with a yaml file name that contains a playbook.

From [the doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html):

> The name of the imported playbook is specified directly without any other option.

But if in your `new.yml`, you simply have `import_playbook: setup.yml` and then you specify the tag as `ansible-playbook` option, it will do the work:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory new.yml --tags=my_tag
```